# What's the sum to $n-2$ terms of the following AP?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:**

> $S_n=3+6+9+12+\dots +T_{n-2}$

**My Approach:**

Since this is clearly an AP, the sum $$S_n=\frac{(n-2)(2.3+(n-2-1)3)}{2}$$
$$\therefore S_n=\frac{(n-2)(6+3n-9)}{2}=\frac{(n-2)(3n-3)}{2}=\frac{3(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$$

Is this correct? I think not, because for $n=1,2$, the sum comes out to be $0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you wrote the sum to be
$$
S_n = (n-2) \frac{2\cdot 3  + (n-2-1)3}{2}
$$
Why is the first $3$ multiplied by 2? In my opinion it should just be 
$$
S_n = (n-2) \frac{3  + (n-2-1)3}{2}
$$

Comment: What you wrote is correct. Yeah! It is just that for $n=2$ if you are looking at the first $n-2$ terms, that is $2-2=0$ terms and so the sum should be zero.

Comment: Perhaps your LHS should be $S_{n-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

$S_n=3\times (1+2+3+\dots+(n-2))$

$\implies S_n=3\times \dfrac {(n-2)(n-1)}2$

$\implies S_n=\dfrac32(n-2)(n-1)$